# Same string.length but different justification of text

Tags: javascript, html, text, justify

I have this question : I copied and pasted lines from a book written in word 2013. These two lines are here in the text area displayed exactely at the same full justification. Next I put the two var stringa1 and var stringa2 in a Javascript code. I hoped the same thing appears as in text area but the result is very different. This appearance was disappointing hence I have coded a lenght for both the stringa1 and stringa2. The lenght was 72 regard the both strings but on the screen output of the executed script is the stringa2 is less long than stringa1. It seems that 72 is not equal to 72 in term of an histogram like way(it is a similitude for better understanding of my problem). Can somebody help me explaining why this happens? Thanks.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html lang="it">


</head>

<body>
<p style="font-family:monospace;">
<textarea cols="72" rows="2">
Ho  l'ordine   di   partire   per  la   zona  di   guerra, quasi improv-
visamente.     Mattina     d'ottobre.    Fatidico    1915.      Servizio
</textarea>

<br/>

<script>

var stringa1="Ho  l'ordine   di   partire   per  la   zona  di   guerra, quasi improv-";

var stringa2="visamente.     Mattina     d'ottobre.    Fatidico    1915.      Servizio";


document.write("<br>");
document.write("["+stringa1+"]"+"L="+stringa1.length+"<br>");
document.write("["+stringa2+"]"+"L="+stringa2.length+"<br>");
document.write("<br>");


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! As your question is written right now it is very hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish.
Please take a moment or two and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to edit your question for a higher chance of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, any series of whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines) is treated as **one space** except in certain special cases. A `textarea` is one of those special cases. If your `document.write` calls were writing inside a `textarea`, you'd get the same behavior as your hardcoded version:

```html
<p style="font-family:monospace;">
<textarea cols="72" rows="2">
Ho  l'ordine   di   partire   per  la   zona  di   guerra, quasi improv-
visamente.     Mattina     d'ottobre.    Fatidico    1915.      Servizio
</textarea>
<br/>
<script>
var stringa1="Ho  l'ordine   di   partire   per  la   zona  di   guerra, quasi improv-";
var stringa2="visamente.     Mattina     d'ottobre.    Fatidico    1915.      Servizio";
document.write("<textarea cols='72' rows='2'>");
document.write(stringa1 + "\n");
document.write(stringa2 + "\n");
document.write("</textarea>");
</script>
```

Other places spaces are not consolidated:

- In a `pre` element
- In any element with the CSS [`white-space` style property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) set to `pre`, `pre-wrap`, `pre-line`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When using document.write, consecutive spaces are merged and thus justification is wrong. That's the indented behavior. If you want justification, replace spaces with non-breakable spaces `&nbsp;`